# Flutter - Drawer: show existing page if exists, not a new instance

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-drawer

The app I am developing attempts to adopt, as much as possible, the most native experience for Android & iOS users.

To do so, the app runs a `CupertinoApp` and a `MaterialApp`.

On iOS, I use the `CupertinoScaffold` showing a `CupertinoTabBar` with `BottomNavigationBarItems`. It performs very well as expected:

- pages are created only once, the first time I click on a tab;
- pages are *restored* when returning to a previously displayed tab: in one of my tab, there is a list and its scroll position is always maintained, persisted.

on Android, the story is different: I am using the `Drawer` widget.
When I click on an entry, I call `Navigator#push` to show the associated page. However, this will keep adding new instances of each entry's page in the stack.

**I don't seem to be able to return to an existing page**. At least, not how I can do it with iOS.

Looking at the `Navigator` I see functions that seem to achieve what I am looking for:

- `popUntil` => will show my existing screen, but at the expanses of all the other ones that will therefore make a sacrifice for the sake of just one page. So much ado for nothing...
- `pushReplacement` => will show a new instance of the target page and destroy the current one. Not desirable.

What am I missing ? How can I achieve that the `CupertinoTabBar` seems to be able to do?

Comment: Maybe you need a Navigator Observer to check the pop or push route and replace it or remove it

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorObserver-class.html

With a observer you can pop or push whenever you want

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. The class you are suggesting offers methods to indeed monitor what is being pushed or popped. You mean I should use it to keep the instance of a route previously navigated to ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved my issue by taking another direction.

Simply put I don't think there is a way, with the `Navigator` to achieve what I want.

The solution I find out was: [Keep state of widgets with Bottom Navigation Bar in Flutter](https://medium.com/@codinghive.dev/keep-state-of-widgets-with-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter-bb732214bd11)

This guide suggests to use a `IndexedStack` that displays only one child at the time while keeping its state.

**So this is how I managed to make it work:**

1. Create your `MaterialApp`
2. Set its `home` to be a custom stateful widget called `MaterialHomePage`
3. This `MaterialHomePage` builds a `Scaffold`:

   - with an `AppBar` and its title (the title of the active page);
   - with a `drawer` and its arguments (more on that later)
   - and the `body` is that so-called wonderful `IndexedStack`:

     - set its `children` to be the list of pages / widgets, the same pages available in the drawer
     - set `index` to be the property `_selectedPageIndex` of your `MaterialHomePage`
   - and with a function that will be triggered when the user chooses a page to navigate to, in which case the usual call to `setState` occurs inside of which you may update the `_selectedPageIndex` property as well as `_selectedPageIndex`property`.
4. The `Drawer`:

   - takes two parameters:

     - the current active page index (defaults to 0 at app launch)
     - a `Function` with the target page title & index
   - must list as many entries (usually `ListTile`) as pages you have declared in the `IndexedStack` displayed in `MaterialHomePage`.
   - upon clic on the entry, it calls the aforementioned function and passes the index of the clicked entry as well as the associated page title.

**At the end, what happens:**

1. The user opens the drawer.
2. The user chooses a new destination (let's say: entry #3).
3. `MaterialHomePage` gets notified (via callback) of the user choice which triggers a `setStage` that will both:

   - update the current page thanks to `IndexedStack` with `index = 3`
   - and update its `AppBar`'s title

and *voilà* there you go: each page gets retained, no loss of state and a smooth navigation.

NB: if the user uses the Android's back button feature, at this point it will close the app since the `Navigator` stack is empty. Maybe there is a way to listen for such an event if you desire to default to the first entry / page (displayed at launch) if the user was in a another page.

NB2: I also wonder if there is a way to animate page transitions.

PS: Let me know if the answers is a fine solution in which case I'll validate it. Or if you find a proper way to achieve it.